# Can Axis 1 work with restrictions

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, axis

I have a web service developed in Axis 2. Called EmployeeService.

EmployeeService.java

```
public class EmployeeService {

    public Employee getEmployee(Employee emp) {
        emp.getTeam().setTeamName("TeamName");
        return emp;
    }
}
```

Employee.java

```
public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String email;
    private Team team;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public Team getTeam() {
        return team;
    }
    public void setTeam(Team team) {
        this.team = team;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", email=" + email
                + ", team=" + team + "]";
    }   
}
```

Team.java

```
public class Team {

    private String businessUnitName;
    private String teamName;

    public String getBusinessUnitName() {
        return businessUnitName;
    }
    public void setBusinessUnitName(String businessUnitName) {
        this.businessUnitName = businessUnitName;
    }
    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }
    public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Team [businessUnitName=" + businessUnitName + ", teamName="
                + teamName + "]";
    }


}
```

For the teamName field in the Team POJO, I added a restriction in the WSDL and I am using the custom WSDL.

```
<simpleType name="teamNameType">
    <restriction base="string">
        <minLength value="0"/>
        <maxLength value="80"/>
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

The service is deployed successfully.

I am accessing the service using Axis 1.

```
EmployeeServiceLocator locator = new EmployeeServiceLocator();
EmployeeServicePortType endpoint = locator.getEmployeeServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint();
Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.setName( "SomeName" );
emp.setAge( new Integer( 21 ) );
emp.setEmail( "test@test.com" );
Team team = new Team();
team.setBusinessUnitName( "businessUnitName" );
emp.setTeam( team );
Employee ret = endpoint.getEmployee( emp );
TeamNameType resTeamName = ret.getTeam().getTeamName();

System.out.println( resTeamName.toString() );
```

From the result, resTeamName does not have any functions to get the data that is coming in the response.

If I print the response to console, I can see that the TeamName is coming as part of the response.

Code to print the response.

```
Call call = ( ( org.apache.axis.client.Stub ) endpoint )._getCall();
SOAPEnvelope envelope = call.getResponseMessage().getSOAPEnvelope();
Document doc = envelope.getAsDocument();

Transformer trans = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
trans.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml" );
trans.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes" );
trans.setOutputProperty( "{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", Integer.toString( 2 ) );

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult( sw );
DOMSource source = new DOMSource( doc );

trans.transform( source, result );
String xmlString = sw.toString();
System.out.println( xmlString );
```

The response printed is

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns:getEmployeeResponse xmlns:ns="http://employee">
      <ns:return>
        <ns:age>21</ns:age>
        <ns:email>test@test.com</ns:email>
        <ns:name>SomeName</ns:name>
        <ns:team>
          <ns:businessUnitName>businessUnitName</ns:businessUnitName>
          <ns:teamName>TeamName</ns:teamName>
        </ns:team>
      </ns:return>
    </ns:getEmployeeResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But I could not find any way to access the TeamName data from the result of the web service.

If I inspect the TeamName object, then also I am not able to see any field that could return me the Object.

[image]

I have also shared my service, in case if some one need to try it out.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/27532041/employee.aar

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Came across this bug.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS-119
please refer Tom Jordahl's comments
"At this point Axis 1.x just doesn't support these kinds of restrictions."
and
"There are no plans to support this in Axis 1.x. Axis2 is using XMLBeans, which I believe generates code to enforce restrictions."

Comment: AXIS-119 doesn't say that Axis 1.x has no support at all for this type of restrictions (you need to read Tom's comment in context); it simply says that restriction *facets* (other than enumerations) are ignored. In Paul's case this means that Axis 1.x will not do anything with the `minLength`/`maxLength` facets. However, it is still expected to map `teamNameType` to `java.lang.String`, and Paul should be able to set a value for the `teamName` property.

Answer (score 0):

Your WSDL is basically incorrect. I had a look at the WSDL in the AAR file, and the `simpleType` definition and its descendants don't have the right namespace. In Eclipse, simply right click the WSDL file and select "Validate", then correct the reported errors. Once the WSDL file is correct, Axis 1.x should be able to generate a stub that allows you to set the `teamName` property. However (as explained in my comment to K Vikas Chandran), Axis 1.x will not enforce the `minLength`/`maxLength` restriction facets.